# Akka actor tracing in not working in Kamon

Tags: java, akka, kamon

I would like to get Akka actor tracing metrics in a Java application.
I enabled tracing in my **application.conf** but I get no tracing metrics.
This topic is way underdocumented.
The Kamon documentation says:

"Please note that even while understanding how to manipulate a TraceContext is very important, some Kamon modules such as our **Akka**, Scala, Spray and Play! modules already provide bytecode instrumentation that automatically creates, propagates and finishes traces and segments in specific conditions, so, you might not need to ever manipulate a TraceContext yourself."

From this I understand that all I have to do is to enable tracing in the configuration file and I should get tracing metrics.
I tried to create a trace context **in Java code** and called `finish()` on it and **I get trace metrics**.

I send data through several actors and I would also be interested in getting some information (for example total processing time; identification of data based on some kind of tagging) when a concrete piece of data arrives to the last actor. I wonder if this can be done from configuration.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For Akka what you get out of the box is automatic trace context propagation (the TraceContext is available in any actor receiving a message sent within a TraceContext) but you need to start the context yourself.
You get automatic tracing for higher level modules like spray where kamon knows your "entry point" for your application.
See: http://kamon.io/integrations/akka/overview/